# Use positions of geometry nodes instances in procedural shader

Tags: geometry-nodes, shaders, shader-nodes, procedural

I have a geometry nodes sphere with several objects instanced on its surface in a spiral. I want to shade a circle on the surface of the sphere at the location of each instance. How can I get the positions of the instances into the shader and use them to shade the sphere?

[Blend file download](https://envs.sh/FNv.blend)

[image: geometry nodes]
[image: shader]

Comment: It looks like the geometry node setup Ico Sphere is missing a [Set Material-node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/material/set_material.html).

Comment: I'm not interested in shading the ico spheres, I want to shade the large UV sphere based on the position of the ico spheres. I did go ahead and add the Set Material node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to realize instances and use a geometry proximity node to get the distance from the sphere of each icoshphere. And don't forget to set the material too

[image]

Since the attributes are geometry based, you'll need to subdivide the sphere a couple of times to get higher res circles. Using a rounded cube can help topology wise

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was what I needed. I actually have an irregularly shaped instanced object (the icosphere in the example), so I had to take the "Points" input to the "Instance on Points" node and use that as the target geometry for "Geometry Proximity" in order to have a circular shaded area for a non-circular object.

Comment: On second thought, that method removes the need to realize instances as well.